# In Aliens, what is the "ornament" that Drake has in these two scenes?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

Watching Aliens again, I know every scene pretty well, but I noticed something new.

The smartgunner "Drake" seems to have some sort of ornament / decoration. I spotted it in two scenes, once it was hanging from his USMC cap, and in another scene it's hanging from the end of his smartgun.

It doesnt look like part of the smartgun (and Vasquez doesn't have the same thing on her gun).

If it was earth in the present day, it reminds me of the sort of ornaments you can buy as a tourist in Mexico. Maybe there is some cultural or religious connection, but this is 2176, so I wouldn't know.

**What is it?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Needs more hand drawn red circles.

Comment: @T.J.L. - I'm way ahead of you, dude.

Comment: Something interesting to note is that this was most likely added by the actor playing Drake himself (Mark Rolston). James Cameron told the actors to "personalize" their stuff as they wanted, to fit their characters. :)  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/trivia?item=tr0794400

Comment: @Ditto Nice trivia - I guess he never would have predicted a chicken bone necklass. Having said that, I do like the grafitti on the weapons and the armor. Really adds to the atmosphere. Especially the armor on Hicks, and Vasquez smartgun which says "ADIOS".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Drake wears a couple of items of eclectic jewellery. Around his neck is a leather thong with a couple of feathers at the end. The original prop is depicted below, part of the [Harry Harris collection](http://www.harryharris.com/feathers.htm).

[image]

And the item he drapes over his smartgun is a chickenbone necklace, also part of the same collection of props.

[image]
<sub><sup>Note replica. Original probably destroyed or recycled by the studio</sup></sub>

You can see it in a bit more detail here.

[image]

Comment: @Valorum Awesome, thanks. You said *eclectic* - do you have any idea why he wears them, or if they represent anything spiritual / religious / good luck / etc? Or is it simply "fashion".

Comment: @vikingsteve - They're reminiscent of the sorts of voodoo charm necklaces you can pick up from trinket sellers. My guess is that they took R&R in Tijuana and someone told him that they're good luck. When colonists are shooting at you and bugs are trying eat your face, who could possibly pass up a chance to buy some good fortune?

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late to the game, but there is a behind the scenes picture where you can clearly see that it is the chicken bone necklace.

[image: black and white behind the scenes picture, three soldiers in combat gear]